# How do I get @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault to work?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, nullpointerexception, findbugs

I've made several attempts at getting package annotation @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault to work for me in a maven project but with no success.
Could someone share a link to a minimal/sample maven project where this is setup (or post the pom.xml and package-info.java and demo class)?

I'm talking about having findbugs processor enforce it for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### How to apply [`@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120331090849/http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.html)

Create a file `package-info.java` in your package where you want to enforce the desired behavior.

In that file, do the following:

```
/**
 * You should do it like this!
 */
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package com.stackoverflow;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

### How *not to* apply `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`

Don't do the following in a Java source file:

```
/**
 * But you shouldn't do it this way!
 */
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package com.stackoverflow;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;

public class Answer { ...
```

Declaring annotations like this is ambiguous.

### Notes

It would be OK to apply the annotation directly on `Answer` class.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;

/**
 * You can do it like this also.
 */
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public class Answer { ...
```

The exact same things apply to [`@ParametersAreNullableByDefault`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120331090849/http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.html) also.

Comment: Android users, you will need to add jsr-305 as a dependency. Google hosts a copy of it for Findbugs which can be used: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305

Comment: Is there a way to apply it to an entire project?

Comment: @AntonyStubbs Haven't tried, but maybe you can create a `package-info.java` at your package structure's top level, say for `com.example.project`, create a `package-info.java` in the `com` folder and test whether the effect of the annotation is recursively applied or not. Just a wild guess that it might work - if not, then I'd think this is the design principle behind the annotation and its effect: tell explicitly in every package where you want this to be the default. My suggestion tho': put it on every class - that's the most visible, easiest to understand.

Answer (score 4):

For **Android** projects (for example when using libraries like Retrofit etc), this is the dependency to put in `app/build.gradle` (as mentioned by @Saket):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I had to add this as well with my Spring Boot project