# Why does someone use @ParametersAreNotNullByDefault?

Tags: java

I have seen this in code around where there is a declaration of

```
@ParametersAreNotNullByDefault 
public class A
{
private String id;

public A(final String id)
{
this.id = id;
}
}
```

What does this annotation buy us ? With this annotation should we not do checks like

```
if (id==null)
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the annotation you're referring to is actually `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`, considering Google has no idea what the annotation `@ParametersAreNotNullByDefault` is at all.

There is some documentation for this annotation [here](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.html), as well as a related SO question (which I believe more or less answers your question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516157/how-do-i-get-parametersarenonnullbydefault-to-work).

Using the implementation of the annotation from [JSR-305](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/), the following code:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public class NonnullTest
{

    public static boolean parameterIsNull(Object o)
    {
        return (o == null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean str = parameterIsNull("foo");
        boolean nul = parameterIsNull(null);

        System.out.println("String returned: " + Boolean.toString(str));
        System.out.println("null returned: " + Boolean.toString(nul));
    }

}
```

Compiles and executes without errors, and prints:

```
String returned: false
null returned: true
```

So it seems that this annotation doesn't actively prevent `null` values being passed via an exception or etc, and that you DO still need to check if your parameters are invalid.

This is consistent with what I've been reading on the JSR-305 project page, which seems to indicate that the point of the annotations it adds is *static code analysis*.

Comment: But does it actually check for null ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simple test case to demonstrate that it doesn't actually check for nulls.

Comment: Oh rats... if I use JetBrains' NotNull it will throw an exception if it violates the condition, but if I use the standard Nonnull (or ParametersAreNonnullByDefault) it won't. Even though IDEA does let me configure the annotations to use, it seems it only instruments classes to check for its own ones. :(