# ParametersAreNonnullByDefault javax annotation on class not doing null checks

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class which is annotated with `ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` javax annotation. But its constructor and methods accept null parameters and don't throw `NullPointerException`.

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
class MyClass {
    private Integer intField;

    public MyClass(Integer intField) {
        this.intField = intField;
    }

    public Integer someMethod(Integer a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

The following lines of code do not throw NullPointerException as I would expect:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(null);
obj.someMethod(null);
```

As per the documentation, "This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that the method parameters in that element are nonnull by default". Where/when is the null check being made for method parameters with this annotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516157/how-do-i-get-parametersarenonnullbydefault-to-work)

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/parametersarenonnullbydefault-annotation.html) may help too.

Comment: Lombok's @NonNull annotation is much more useful as it implements the null check in the code. It is a more concrete implementation showing what 'must' be done and not just what 'should' be done.